# PHP Trim not working into a Wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying apply Trim in a $title string, and save the trimmed words in $TitleUTF, but the function returns the same value in both variables

```
class Lavoz_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array(), $id = 0) {

        $title = $item->title;
        // Remove blank spaces from title //
        $titleUTF = trim($title);

        // paste the image url without spaces //
        $output .= '<img src="'. $urlactual .'/img/'. $titleUTF .'.jpg" alt="'. $title .'">';


    }
}
```

I read all the similar post here, but none of them works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello use below code to remove spaces from wordpress title but make sure you are getting title in variable `$title`.

```
class Lavoz_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array(), $id = 0) {

        $title = $item->title;
        // Remove blank spaces from title //
        $titleUTF = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $title('', false)))

        // paste the image url without spaces //
        $output .= '<img src="'. $urlactual .'/img/'. $titleUTF .'.jpg" alt="'. $title .'">';


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @raju_eww . Yes, $title saves the title good, at least I see it as a output in alt="".
The code not works, breaks the webpage. I tried too adding ";" at the end of "false)))"

Comment: Worked!! but using:

$titleUTF = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $title));

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regular expression to replace non UTF-8 spaces and new lines:

```
$title = preg_replace('#(^\s+|\s+$)#isu', '', $title)
```